# Design for a machine learning artificial intelligence framework

Tags: frameworks, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

This is a community wiki which aims to provide a good design for a machine learning/artificial intelligence framework (ML/AI framework).

Please contribute to the design of a language-agnostic framework which would allow multiple ML/AI algorithms to be plugged into a single framework which:

- runs the algorithms with a user-specified data set.
- facilitates learning, qualification, and classification.
- allows users to easily plug in new algorithms.
- can aggregate or create an ensemble of the existing algorithms.
- can save/load the progress of the algorithm (i.e. save the network and weights of a neural network, save the tree of a decision tree, etc.).

What is a good design for this sort of ML/AI framework?

Comment: SO is not meant to be a discussion site. Its raison d'etre is for specific questions with specific answers.

Comment: Not really. It still seems way too open ended to me (changing the last sentence hardly changes the nature). But there's no point trying to convince me anyway since I've already voted to close and that's non-retractable in SO. You should concentrate on convincing everyone else :-) Keep in mind that's _my_ opinion - I don't run the site, I have the same powers here as anyone else.

Comment: Let assume for a moment that this problem has been brought up before, perhaps it would be more in the nature of S.O. to ask for appropriate outside references to solutions, discussion, and places to create further discussion on the topic.  more likely to get a useful answer that way.

Comment: @paxdiablo Maybe I should add the "subjective" tag :)...

Comment: Remember guys... this is a community wiki now, so if you think that it should ask a more specific question, then edit it. I don't mind :).

Comment: There's a lot of stupid questions on SO too. At least this one is interesting, even if it's not a "question".

Comment: Concur with Benny: SO has enough uber-detailed API questions right now... let's have something a bit more profound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps one can start by looking at the design of existing open source ML/AI frameworks. To name a few: Weka, RapidMiner, KNIME, Orange, ..

Comment: +1 for some great references to existing projects, and Weka in particular!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one I made for PHP: http://neuralmesh.com

Comment: How easy is it to add other ML/AL algorithms to your framework? Is it for neural networks only?

Comment: Only for neural networks so far. It is open-source so hopefully in the future more algorithms will be available.

Comment: +1 for the good job on your framework... it looks really good. Nice web site too! Did you use 960.gs?